# This jQuery code won't work. Beginner Here.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just started practicing with jQuery, but I can't seem to get any of the functions to work. This code below is an exercise I've been trying to run, but it won't output the desired result. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www/w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
      content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>change2.html</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(changeMe);

            function changeMe(){
                $("#output").html("I've changed");
                  }
                  //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Using the document.ready mechanism</h1>
    <div id = "output">
        Did this change?
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: did you add jquery reference properly to your page? and the file is existing? check your console and tell us what is the error.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?  do you have a file named jquery-1.4.2.min.js in the same directory as this source file?

Comment: replace `src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"` with `src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The code works. The problem probably is the script location, as has been suggested.

Comment: If you are just starting, go to http://jquery.com and get the latest version. Yours is really outdated. And as the others said, you're probably not linking it properly.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery 1.4.2 was the most recent version when my textbook was published. Replacing the src reference with jQuery's URL solved the problem, thanks for that suggestion. The version on my computer is 2.0.3, but it won't run when I reference it for some reason. All of the files from the jQuery download appear in my Finder windows (Mac user here), but for some reason there's no single file they all came in. I'm guessing I could solve this problem by putting all the individual files from the library into a single file within all of my websites' directories.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bN4Yv/ (That example is using jQuery 2.0.2, but it would work with 1.4 too.)

The problem is probably that jquery-1.4.2.min.js isn't in the same folder as the html file.

I would probably use the shorthand suggested by andrew though:

```
$(function() {
    $("#output").html("I've changed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
   $(document).ready(changeMe);
```

to

```
   $(function(){
       changeMe();
   });
```

Comment: I thought that when calling a function it should be followed by parenthesis eg myFunction(); ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can pass functions around as objects too though, so `$(function(){ changeMe(); });` doesn't need the function wrapping the call to `changeMe`, it can just go ahead and pass in `changeMe` like this: `$(changeMe);`

Comment: You are calling the function `ready` and not `changeMe` you are passing a pointer to the function `changeMe` to `ready` so when the document load event fires, jquery will know that is has to call `changeMe`. I suggest reading through the jquery lib in your spare time, just to get some idea of how it works http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js